# sudo apt install catkin not working

Tags: ros, catkin, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, arduino#ros#raspberry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm a newbie, so sorry if this is really obvious. I'm following the Tutorials instructions having just installed ROS on Ubuntu Mate. The current step says

> ```
> $ cd ~/catkin_ws/
> >     $ catkin_make
> ```

but when I enter "catkin_make" terminal returns

> ```
> The program 'catkin_make' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
> sudo apt install catkin
> ```

So I do that, and get

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

It then ends at that. How can I fix this and continue with the tutorials?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258444/sudo-apt-install-catkin-not-working./) by [JGHunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/29907/jghunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2017-04-02

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-04-03**:
what ROS distro are you using????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, going through the basic tutoril  again making sure to run through all the steps as @bonzi suggests is good.

> ```
> The program 'catkin_make' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
> sudo apt install catkin
> ```

Unintuitive though, this error can also happen when your terminal can't find the command in directories in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.
So make sure `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is set appropriately (e.g. by `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` etc.)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. Did you follows the tutorial properly, because you have to source your environment. Follow this tutorial here, [catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). Once you have installed the workspace, you need to install ROS dependencies, its up to you to choose.

I installed ROS indigo so you can follow this tutorial [ros indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu). Make sure to correctly follow all the instructions mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) with karma: 23 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How you install the catkin is depending on what ROS distro you have.... for example by `indigo`, normally as:

> $sudo apt-get install ros-<distro_name>-catkin

where distro name are **Hydro, Indigo, Kinetic** etc, so assuming you have installed indigo then do:

> $sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-catkin

instead of

> $sudo apt install catkin

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fferri](https://answers.ros.org/users/6966/fferri/) on 2019-05-21**:
This solved the problem for me

**Comment by [virgincoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/72924/virgincoder/) on 2021-07-17**:
I am trying it for neotic, does not works !!
Any idea ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-17**:
The correct name of the ROS distribution is `noetic`, not `neotic`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I also had this issue. The problem was that I forgot to source my ros environment.
Execute the following command in your terminal:

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

Try to use catkin as if where already installed. E.g: catkin_make in your workspace.

If works, remember to add this line to your bash
echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

---

Originally posted by [Ferrera](https://answers.ros.org/users/30668/ferrera/) with karma: 51 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/45491/lobby/) on 2019-09-08**:
good, it works. :)

**Comment by [hassaanaero](https://answers.ros.org/users/64113/hassaanaero/) on 2020-11-26**:
i  did what you recommended, i first sourced the environment : source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
then tried installing catkin using this command : sudo apt install catkin but the terminal responded with issues

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
catkin : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

kindly put  up your valuable suggestion